# The output in VS code doesn't appear in terminal

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

i have used debugger and try to debug simple program but no output appear in terminal

photo of the program:

[image: 1]

Comment: I am not really familiar with VS code, but as far as I know, the output is in the output tab, not the terminal.

Comment: also output tab is empty

Comment: Output to `stdout` is often line buffered. Try to add `\n` to your print. Or add `fflush(stdout);` after printing

Comment: Check "Debug Console" during debugging..

Comment: same https://prnt.sc/B_ou1dCteX5G

Comment: Don't forget to add a newline to the end of the output: `printf("rew\n");` for example.  Your output should then contain `3#rew`.  If you want the `3#` on a separate line, consider using `puts()` instead: `puts("3#"); puts("rew");`.

Comment: Did you install MinGW properly?

Also you should try compiling it and running it using the CLI commands in the terminal

- `gcc main.c -o main` (to compile and create an executable file)

- `.\main.exe` (to run the executable)

Comment: yes it works well https://prnt.sc/GE8Bd6tprb9G

Answer (score 0):

If program was well compiled - then you are a victim of buffered `stdout` stream, that is used by default with `printf` function.

Changing call to add `\n` at the end will solve the problem for you. `printf("your tex\n")`.

See this SO post to understand background: [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

Comment: I think the problem is in the terminal. when using scanf() when I enter input. what I write does not appear in the terminal and can't enter inputs when I force stop the program the inputs I wrote appear and are executed as CMD, not C program

Comment: You do not use scanf in your code.

Comment: another code ..